# HDInsight and Talend Open Studio for Big Data

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, talend, azure-hdinsight

I am currently working on a project in which I need to connect Talend open Studio for Big Data (v 6.3.1) to an Azure’s HDInsight (3.5) Hadoop Cluster. So far, I am trying a simple example which consists in creating an Hive Table.

For that, I am using the following diagram:

[image]

The hive connection was configured as followed:

[image]

… and please find below the specifications of the tHiveCreateTable_1 node:

[image]

By running this process:
· The specified container and deployment Blob is created (see image below) - which make me believe that everything is ok with the Windows Storage Configuration

[image]

· However the tHiveCreateTable_1 node has an error (see image below)

[image]

· I strongly believe that it´s something related with the Hostname and Port;
· I tried to use the host name of the cluster and the hostname of the Hive server that we can find in Ambari (see image below)

[image]

· But none of them worked as expected.

Has any one tried something similar to this?

Note: It seems reasonably important to say that the Azure version supported by Talend is 3.4, however, I am using 3.5, it might be it.

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Some suggestion for improve your content. Your screenshots are too blurred, especially for the screenshot about error. Could you supply clarity screenshots for helping us analysis the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the offical [docuemnt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-component-versioning) about the differences between Hadoop components and versions available with HDInsight, HDInsight 3.5 is based on Hortonworks Data Platform(HDP) 2.5, but HDI 3.4 is based on HDP 2.4. However, there is not big version difference for their Hive componets or other componets. So, my suggestion is that you can try to create a HDI 3.4 using the same Azure Storage account for your current HDI 3.5, without more effects for your needs.